# How can I find the measure of $B=\{(x,y,z) \in\mathbb R^3| \; x^2+y^2+4z^2 \le3, \;x^2-y^2+4z^2\le1, \; z\ge 0\}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, multiple-integral

### $B=\{(x,y,z) \in\mathbb R^3| \; x^2+y^2+4z^2 \le3, \;x^2-y^2+4z^2\le1, \; z\ge 0\}$

---

The question is similar to that which I shared in another topic. Also here, the set is defined by an ellipsoid, an elliptic hyiperboloid and by the positive half-space of z.

Therefore, I relize that I have to solve $\iiint_B1 \;dxdydz$ after studing or changing the equations correctly. Are the cylindrical coordinates useful for the solution? Is it the only way?

I trust in you!

Comment: Yes, it is. @MarkMcClure, can you explain me how you found the limits of integration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I solve this triple integral $\iiint_{B} y\;dxdydz$ on a defined set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842607/how-can-i-solve-this-triple-integral-iiint-b-y-dxdydz-on-a-defined-set)

Comment: @PHPirate I wrote that the topic is simular but I opened it to understand better how solve this kind of integral.

Comment: Of course you can always ask for a better of different explanation, but in that case please mention the differences and why you are asking a question which looks so similar. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry and I thank you for this advice! Surely, I'll be so the next time.

Comment: No problem :) remember there is always time to edit your question to improve it, even after it is marked as for example duplicate.